# Can anyone help to identify this picture of a relative wearing a possibly Polish/Russian/Prussian uniform?

Tags: military, 20th-century, identification, uniform, photograph

[image: four seated men wearing uniforms]I found this photo and tried to match to uniforms of the time around 1911. Can’t find one with similar pockets or stripes. Can you help to identify? My sister says person on left is grandfather. They think he came from Poland when it was occupied by Russia but are not positive.

Adjusted image:
[image: Adjusted image]

Comment: Why did you look at uniforms from around 1911? It sounds like there is something you aren't telling us. Any other information you can give about the people in the photo or about the photo itself (e.g. photographic studio) could potential help in identifying the uniforms.

Comment: Probably Russian, as it doesn't look Polish and certainly not German.

Comment: Four men, but which one?

Comment: I question if these are even military uniforms. The one middle left you could make an argument for based off the boots, and cuff stripes but they look almost industrious instead.

Comment: The hats look vaguely like Serbian military hats of the early 20th century.

Comment: Very strange. Brest pockets on the tunic resemble some of the Russian uniforms, but hats definitely not. Two guys on the left have boots and something  looks like feather on their hats, so they could be officers or cavalry .Guys on the right have footwraps, so they may have been enlisted man and probably infantry.

Comment: Definitely not Russian. The hats resemble Ukrainian fashion. I would guess they are some Ukrainian nationalists. Anyway, they are definitely from Eastern Europe

Comment: For me closest to it would be Sikh soldier uniform. The British style is prevalent, but it looks like a mix of uniform elements. 3rd from the left is resembling Indian army uniform, all from WWI era, of course.